# Moving a Magento installation

Tags: magento-1.9, database, css, migration

My customer has a working Magento installation, where they are taking regular sales.  We have created them a new installation in a sub-directory of the working site.  It is a completely different site, new artwork, CSS pages, everything.  I need to know the best way to move the new site onto the root directory, and migrate all sales, customer, products, images, everything.

What I tried first, is to, change the database connection in the local.xml to the current database, and everything seemed to look fine from the back end, but when I went to the site it now showed the original pages.  I changed the base URL in the Web section of the admin, and now I have a conglomeration of both sites.  So, I put everything back as it was for the moment, till I can get a better solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way (short of a lot of manual work) to migrate sales data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from which version of Magento your are upgrading. Take a look at the Magento release notes to see if you have to do additional things or script.

You're doing a upgrade oldsite(current) to new site. So make good database backups before upgrading!

Some updates go flawless, you can use the same database again, set the right template(and additional settings for the new site) and everything works.
You've to use the database and also the media directory.

But most of the time the new website has some site specifics which do not allow you to just migrate and you are stuck with two separate sites with separate settings.

Comment: Both installations are the same version.

Comment: Than setting the correct template and base url should be enough... And maybe some settings for new modules